# A natural system of equations

Tags: mathematics, rebus

What goes in the question mark? (Same for both equations). It is something very well-known.

[image]

Hint:

> This transcends those other 2018 puzzles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value of ? is

> e

because

> e ~= 2.718281828459045

and then

> For a slightly different definition of minus (changing that digit to 0),
>
> ```
> 2.718 - 2nd (digit) = 2.018
> ```
>
> And then again for the second line,
>
> ```
> e - 2nd - 6th would be 2.0182018...
> ```
>
> or "this year this year".

Hints/title:

> Natural system = e is the base of the natural logarithm, and this answer "transcends" since e is a transcendental number.

Comment: Markiplier would be so proud!!

Answer (score 11):

***Warning:*** *This is the mathematician-with-no-humour approach*

> Numbers are numbers, so "$2^{nd}$" is $2$ and "$6^{th}$" is $6$.

Next:

> You have two unknown values, "**?**" and "**this year**", that I rename $x$ and $y$ just because.

Now the system is just:

> $x-2=y$ and $x-2-6=y*y$

Which I can solve like in high school and get:

> $x=\frac{5\pm i\sqrt{23}}{2}$

Which is obviously not what you were waiting for.

Comment: As a mathematician without humour also, please, take my upvote (+1)

Comment: If you want a real solution maybe take 2nd as 1/2 and 6th as 1/6? [Wolfram|Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-1%2F2%3Dy,x-1%2F2-1%2F6%3Dy*y)

Comment: But this answer is funny